# Long time to load picture from web in a UITableCellView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I'm reading a file in which are stored some URL to pics. I will present this pics like follow:

[image]

To do that stuff I wrote the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
    HistoryCustomCell *historyCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    historyCustomCell.labelTitle.text = [sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    historyCustomCell.labelContent.text = [sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    if ([[sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]isEqualToString:stringDate]) {
        historyCustomCell.labelDate.text = [[sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    } else {
        historyCustomCell.labelDate.text = [sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    }

    if (![[sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imgUrl"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        CALayer *cellImageLayer = historyCustomCell.imageView.layer;
        [cellImageLayer setCornerRadius:33.5];
        [cellImageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sortedArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"suggested"] ] isEqualToString:@"1"] && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sortedArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"breakingNews"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            // SUGGESTED
            [cellImageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:161.0 green:199.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
            [cellImageLayer setBorderWidth:3.0];
        }
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sortedArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"breakingNews"] ] isEqualToString:@"1"] && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sortedArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"suggested"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            // BREAKING NEWS
            [cellImageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:254.0 green:214.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
            [cellImageLayer setBorderWidth:3.0];
        }
        if ([[sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"is_unread"] intValue] == 1) {
            historyCustomCell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } else {
            historyCustomCell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:239.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }

        NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[sortedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imgUrl"]];
        UIImage *imgThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl]];
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(67, 67);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [imgThumb drawInRect:imageRect];
        historyCustomCell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    } else {
        [historyCustomCell.imageView setImage:nil];
    }

    return historyCustomCell;
}
```

When
 I try to run the app on the device the view will be draw like the image, but it takes too much to load pictures and the UITableView are very slow to scroll it. I guess it's a problem because the connection to receive the image, how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**
I guess I could use this method to solve my issue:

```
- (void) loadImageFromWeb:(NSURL *)urlImg andImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlImg];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage *imgThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                   CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
                                   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                                   CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                                   [imgThumb drawInRect:imageRect];
                                   imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                                   [hud hide:YES];
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                                   [hud hide:YES];
                               }

                           }];
}
```

With this method it should load the UIImageView without lag on the GUI right?

Comment: You are using the synchronous process for downloading the image try to use the Asynchronous image downloading http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/

Comment: Try to have a look about my edit, I guess it can be a good solution.

Comment: Welcome have a great coding

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *imgThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl]];
```

The line above is a synchronous call.  This means that the rest of the code will not run until this line is finished downloading all of the data from the server and turning it into a UIImage.  What you want to do is an Asynchronous request.

You can search how to perform Asynchronous URL request.  Usually this involves a delegate pattern or a completion block which will execute once the image has finished downloading.  This will allow for the rest of the code to run and the UI of the application will not freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Here s the problem

`UIImage *imgThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl]];`

From the docs

> **dataWithContentsOfURL**
>
> This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects,
>   and can also be used for reading short files synchronously. Do not use
>   this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For
>   network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens
>   of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and
>   in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

To download image and still have smooth scrolling behavior you need to download the image **asynchronously**. In your case whats happening is that the execution on main thread is blocked until the image is downloaded. To avoid this you must download your image on a separate thread and when its done downloading get the `UIImage` object and set it to its respective cell.

There are a lot of ways to download. Very old approach is to use `NSOperations`, or as the docs suggest use [`dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:) instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL`.

If you are using AFNetworking, it has a sweet `UIImageView` category. Just include that and call

```
[historyCustomCell.imageView setImageWithURL:imgUrl]
```

This will download asynchronously and also caches the image.